# Using non-finite after "but" and "except"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, bare-infinitives

There is a rule stated on [englishgrammar.org](http://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/) saying that we use bare infintives

> **After some prepositions like except, but, save and than**
>
> She can do everything but cook.
>
> She did nothing except cry.

However, we can see usage of both Gerund and to + verb 1 after them.

> “She wasn't doing a thing that I could see, **except standing** there
>   leaning on the balcony railing, holding the universe together.”  ―
>   J.D. Salinger ([goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/244426-she-wasn-t-doing-a-thing-that-i-could-see-except))

Or:

> "But Maclean had taken his share of the punch, and vowed that no
>   gentleman should leave his table after the bowl was brewed; so **there
>   was nothing for it but to sit** and hear Jacobite toasts and Gaelic
>   songs, till all were tipsy and staggered off to the bed or the barn
>   for their night's rest."

So, what's the rule for non-finite verbs' usage after these words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the first two examples, and read it without the but/except

> She can [do everything but] cook.
>
> She did [nothing except] cry

We have normal sentences- subject, modal and verb- with a **but** in the middle.

In the third sentence, you have to take out a bit more:

> She was[n't doing a thing that I could see, except] standing

You can now see that it's a past continuous sentence, with **standing** as an active participle.

In the third example, there is no subject, no modal. You can't take anything out to make a complete sentence.

> there was nothing for it but to sit

Here, the writer doesn't say explicitly **who** is sitting: he is talking about the activity of sitting, so you have to use an infinitive (to sit) or gerund (sitting).